# c# parsing xml again with XDocument

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

I have looked at a lot of help files and a lot of similar questions to mine but I am not able to get further than returning the descendant collection.

What I want to achieve is to get an array that contains the values of all the `id` attributes of the `tag` elements that have `ph` or `bpt` children (not those that have `st`) in the XPath of `xliff\file\header\tag-defs`

Here is the xml. I stripped out other tags and it is truncated after the header element, for simplicity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xliff xmlns:sdl="http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0" version="1.2" sdl:version="1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<file original="\\txl-app1\scncontent\AUDIO\en\Testing\SubtitleXML-FTS\13Mar16_Game.xml" source-language="en-US" datatype="x-sdlfilterframework2" target-language="da-DK">
<header>
  <reference>
    <internal-file form="base64"></internal-file>
  </reference>
  <sdl:ref-files>
    <sdl:ref-file uid="0" id="http://www.sdl.com/Sdl.FileTypeSupport.Native.Xml/OriginalXmlFile" name="DF44_13Mar16_Speech_BirthdayGame.xml" o-path="\\txl-app1\scncontent\AUDIO\en\Testing\SubtitleXML-FTS\13Mar16_Speech_BirthdayGame.xml" date="04/25/2016 18:55:53" descr="The original XML file." expected-use="Generation" />
  </sdl:ref-files>
  <file-info xmlns="http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0">
    <value key="SDL:FileId">c6550fcb-8e69-428a-a0a8-6447918a97a2</value>
    <value key="SDL:CreationDate">04/25/2016 16:16:55</value>
    <value key="SDL:OriginalFilePath">\\txl-app1\content\Testing\SubtitleXML-FTS\13Mar16_Game.xml</value>
    <value key="SDL:InputFilePath">\\txl-app1\content\en\Testing\SubtitleXML-FTS\13Mar16_Game.xml</value>
    <value key="SDL:OriginalEncoding">utf-8</value>
    <value key="HasUtf8Bom">true</value>
    <value key="IsFragment">false</value>
    <value key="SchemaLocation"></value>
    <value key="SDL:AutoClonedFlagSupported">True</value>
    <value key="xmlDeclaration">true</value>
    <value key="SDLWS:AssetId">1489743</value>
    <value key="SDLWS:DocId">3043144</value>
    <value key="SDLWS:TaskId">1382715</value>
    <value key="SDLWS:ScopingMode">0</value>
    <value key="SDLWS:CreationDate">2016-04-26T00:16:55Z</value>
    <value key="SDLWS:ProjectName">SubtitleXML-FTS_da_DK_20160425_111419</value>
    <value key="SDLWS:UserName">BI</value>
    <value key="ParagraphTextDirections"></value>
    <sniff-info>
      <detected-encoding detection-level="Certain" encoding="utf-8" />
      <detected-source-lang detection-level="Guess" lang="en-US" />
      <props>
        <value key="HasUtf8Bom">true</value>
        <value key="IsFragment">false</value>
        <value key="SchemaLocation"></value>
        <value key="xmlDeclaration">true</value>
      </props>
    </sniff-info>
  </file-info>
  <sdl:filetype-info>
    <sdl:filetype-id>Custom XML v 1.2.0.0 (WS:SubtitleXML-FTS)</sdl:filetype-id>
  </sdl:filetype-info>
  <fmt-defs xmlns="http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0">
    <fmt-def id="1">
      <value key="Italic">True</value>
      <value key="TextColor">Black</value>
    </fmt-def>
  </fmt-defs>
  <tag-defs xmlns="http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0">
    <tag id="7">
      <bpt name="i" seg-hint="Include" word-end="false">&lt;i&gt;</bpt>
      <ept name="i" word-end="false">&lt;/i&gt;</ept>
      <fmt id="1" />
    </tag>
    <tag id="3">
      <ph name="Sub" seg-hint="Include">&lt;Sub tc="01:05:00:08 01:05:04:26" WidthAllowed="75"/&gt;</ph>
    </tag>
    <tag id="4">
      <ph name="Sub" seg-hint="Include">&lt;Sub tc="01:05:05:00 01:05:08:24" WidthAllowed="60"/&gt;</ph>
    </tag>
    <tag id="5">
      <ph name="Sub" seg-hint="Include">&lt;Sub tc="01:05:08:28 01:05:13:04" WidthAllowed="60"/&gt;</ph>
    </tag>
    <tag id="6">
      <ph name="Sub" seg-hint="Include">&lt;Sub tc="01:05:13:08 01:05:17:22" WidthAllowed="60"/&gt;</ph>
    </tag>
    <tag id="8">
      <ph name="Sub" seg-hint="Include">&lt;Sub tc="01:05:17:26 01:05:22:11" WidthAllowed="60"/&gt;</ph>
    </tag>
    <tag id="9">
      <ph name="Sub" seg-hint="Include">&lt;Sub tc="01:05:21:21 01:05:27:13" WidthAllowed="90"/&gt;</ph>
    </tag>
    <tag id="10">
      <ph name="Sub" seg-hint="Include">&lt;Sub tc="01:05:27:17 01:05:33:02" WidthAllowed="75"/&gt;</ph>
    </tag>
    <tag id="13">
      <ph name="zwnj" word-end="false" seg-hint="Include">&lt;zwnj dir="1" spc="20"/&gt;</ph>
    </tag>
    <tag id="16">
      <ph name="Sub" seg-hint="Include">&lt;Sub tc="01:41:20:04 01:41:21:24" WidthAllowed="30"/&gt;</ph>
    </tag>
    <tag id="0">
      <st>&lt;XMLsubtitlefile"&gt;</st>
    </tag>
    <tag id="1">
      <st>&lt;Subtitles&gt;</st>
    </tag>
    <tag id="2">
      <st>&lt;NonVOsubs&gt;</st>
    </tag>
    <tag id="11">
      <st>&lt;/NonVOsubs&gt;</st>
    </tag>
    <tag id="12">
      <st>&lt;VOsub tc="01:41:01:17 01:41:09:27" WidthAllowed="120"&gt;</st>
    </tag>
    <tag id="14">
      <st>&lt;/VOsub&gt;</st>
    </tag>
    <tag id="15">
      <st>&lt;NonVOsubs&gt;</st>
    </tag>
    <tag id="17">
      <st>&lt;/NonVOsubs&gt;</st>
    </tag>
    <tag id="18">
      <st>&lt;/Subtitles&gt;</st>
    </tag>
    <tag id="19">
      <st>&lt;/XMLsubtitlefile&gt;</st>
    </tag>
  </tag-defs>
</header>
<body>...
```

Code-wise I tried different versions, but this is where I am at:

```
private static XDocument xliff;

public static List<XElement> GetTagArray(string FilePath)
{
    xliff = XDocument.Load(Path.GetFullPath(FilePath));
    XNamespace ns = "http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0";
    var elements = xliff.Descendants().Elements(ns + "tag-defs").Elements().Select(e => e.Elements(ns + "ph")).ToList();

//and here I am stuck as not matter what I do above it returns empty...

}
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with XDocument, but I think normally you start out with xDocument.Root(), or in your case xliff.Root(). See if that affects anything.

Comment: sdlxliff files have 2 namespaces for one and `tag` is sdlxliff specific, you need `XNamespace sdl = @"http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0";` and perhaps `xliff.Descendants(sdl + "tag")` to get each `tag`.

Comment: Thanks @Jesse. I noticed after posting. I way able the retrieve the `tag-defs` collection. Now it is probably the lambda expression is the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested code, but try something like the following:

```
XNamespace sdl = @"http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0";
XNamespace ns = @"urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2";
foreach (var tag in xliff.Descendants(sdl + "tag"))
{
    foreach (var ph in tag.Elements(sdl + "ph"))
    {
        // Code here to process
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, this looks good. I did notice that it is the same `sdl` ns. This line now returns the ids: `Debug.WriteLine(ph.Parent.Attribute("id").Value);` Now only question is how to do a lambda expression on it so I can get this to an array instead of a `foreach` loop...

Comment: Bingo. Here is the lambda expression: `var elements = xliff.Descendants().Elements(ns + "tag-defs").Elements(ns + "tag").Elements(ns + "ph").Select(e => e.Parent.Attribute("id")).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

The solution with help from Jesse Good is:

```
private static XDocument xliff;

public static int[] GetTagArray(string FilePath)
{
    xliff = XDocument.Load(Path.GetFullPath(FilePath));
    XNamespace ns = "http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0";
    int[] elements = xliff.Descendants().Elements(ns + "tag-defs").Elements(ns + "tag").Elements(ns + "ph").Select(e => Int32.Parse(e.Parent.Attribute("id").Value)).ToArray();
    int[] elements2 = xliff.Descendants().Elements(ns + "tag-defs").Elements(ns + "tag").Elements(ns + "bpt").Select(e => Int32.Parse(e.Parent.Attribute("id").Value)).ToArray();

    int[] intarray = elements.Concat(elements2).ToArray();
    Array.Sort(intarray);

    return intarray;
}
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Comment: I should mention you are doing a little too much though, prob could shorten to `return xliff.Descendants(ns + "tag").Elements(ns + "ph").Select(e => e.Parent.Attribute("id")).ToList();` and no need for the null check at the end as it will return an empty list if there are none.

Comment: Wow, thanks. For pointing out both of these. Then I realized, I need to go farther here. It works great, so long as there are only standard placeholders in the xliff. As soon as I hit the beginning placeholders `bph` they are listed out of sequence in the `tag-defs` element. They are also need to be part of the array. And the array needs to be an Int[] array. I wonder if this is possible in one neat expression. Do you have an advice?

Comment: I updated the code with my current approach. The only reason I left the `tag-defs` element in there because I know I have to revisit this code as there may be more `file` elements in the xliff. So I will need to select which file I want to return from the xliff. Any suggestion on that?

Comment: `As soon as I hit the beginning placeholders bph they are listed out of sequence in the tag-defs element.` I couldnt understand what you exactly meant for this, if you post a separate question I will look later. For `file` elements, you can use a similar approach to what you already have `xliff.Descendents(ns + "file").Where(e => Path.GetFileName((string)e.Attribute("original)") == "myfilename.xml");`

Comment: Note that `file` is in the xliff namespace though.

Comment: @JesseGood -- Thanks for the reply. OK, tracking on the filename, I will try it. I updated the XML code in the question above to another file that has these `bpt` and `ept` children. I need to return all inline element ids in an `int[]` array. Can you give me some advice on simplifying my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110329/discussion-between-ib11-and-jesse-good).